# How to solve the "System.Tuple defined multiple times issue"?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I work on a project target WP 7.5 and above, I add a packages using the Nuget in VS 2012 which name is Coding4fun(Controls).

After that, the IDE give me a warning,

> Warning   1   The predefined type 'System.Tuple' is defined in multiple
>   assemblies in the global alias; using definition from
>   'c:\Users\Gao\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\TFSGit\xicihutong\packages\Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls.2.0.5\lib\wp71\Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls.dll'  C:\Users\Gao\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\TFSGit\xicihutong\xicihutong\CSC xicihutong

The app runs OK, but how to solve this warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From  [`Compiler Warning (level 1) CS1685`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xys0hxk.aspx)

> This error occurs when a predefined system type such as `System.Tuple`
>   is found in two assemblies. One way this can happen is if you are
>   referencing mscorlib from two different places, such as trying to run
>   the.Net Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1 side-by-side.
>
> The compiler will use the definition from only one of the assemblies.

This problem occurs probably `System.Tuple` is defined in two different assemblies. Probably your `Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls.dll` has too besides `mscorlib.dll`.

If you want to look them both you can check them;

- Get a decompiler like [`ILSpy`](http://ilspy.net/) or [`Jetbrains dotPeek`](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).
- Add all 3rd party assemblies.
- Search for `System.Tuple`

> But how to solve this warning?

You can define your 3rd party assemblies reference some aliases. You can follow in your project

```
Reference -> Properties -> Aliases ->
```

And change `"global"` to something different.

Check out for information [`extern alias (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks，after setting the alias, everything goes to normal :)

Answer (score 1):

Newer version of c4f toolkit has resolved this issue.